# Get related models in SQLAlchemy 

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have various models chained in [SQLAlchemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy) (has many, belongs to, etc.). Is there a way of finding the related models given ones instance?

Something like:

```
usersModelInstance.getRelatedTables() // This should provide an array or something with the related tables of users (orders, logins, posts, etc.).
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure quite what you want -- a list of tables or a list of mapped classes?

In either case, first build a list of properties for your mapped *object*:

```
# Import sqlalchemy so we can use it
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Rename the OP's object to `obj`
obj = usersModelInstance

# Build a list of only relationship properties
relation_properties = filter(
    lambda p: isinstance(p, sa.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty),
    sa.orm.object_mapper(obj).iterate_properties
)
```

Note that you can use the `sa.orm.class_mapper(cls)` function if you don't
currently have a handle on an entity *instance*, but only a mapped class.

Now, in the first case where you want a list of the related *tables*, do:

```
related_tables = [prop.target for prop in relation_properties]
```

In the second case where you might want a list of the related mapped classes,
do:

```
related_classes = [prop.mapper.class_ for prop in relation_properties]
```

Hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: fyi, passing a lambda to `filter()` is not a good idea - it's better and more performant to use a list comprehension instead