# How can I find the correct class to use when adding SQLAlchemy models through relations?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Might be a bit of an inelegant question title, but hopefully this skeleton setup explains things a little more clearly:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Number(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'number'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('numbers'))
    value = Column(String)


joe = User(name='Joe')
joe.numbers = [
    # Here we need to know that the class we want is named "Number".
    # However, in some contexts (think abstract base classes or mixins) we might
    # not necessarily know that, or have a way to import/reference it.
    Number(value='212-555-1234'),
    Number(value='201-555-1111'),
    Number(value='917-555-8989')]
```

Basically there is a table of `User`s, and each `User` can have an arbitrary number of `Number`s associated with it.

Is there a clean way, through the attributes of `User` alone, to find a reference to the `Number` class (and be able to create instances from it) *without* importing `Number` directly? The best I've come up with, with considerable influence from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221145/get-related-models-in-sqlalchemy), is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_mapper
number_class = object_mapper(joe).relationships['numbers'].mapper.class_
joe.numbers = [number_class(value='212-555-1234') ...]
```

... but this seems rather obtuse, and I'm not fully comfortable relying on it.

The most valid reason I can think to want to be able to do this is in the case of mixins -- if there were some base class that needed the ability to append new numbers to a user without concrete knowledge of what class to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but I'd argue that the easiest (and clean enough) is to store what you need on the User class, because your User class *is* already implementation bound to the Number class, in that it imports and uses Number when creating the relationship. So you could add a User.add_number() method where you pass args to add number, and just have it create the Numbers and store on self.